# REST API Design - Best practice for private resource fields

Tags: rest, api, authentication, get, endpoint

A `GET` user response for a user that opted to have their profile private might look like:

For the **user** itself, when **authorized**:

```
{
    "id": 123,
    "uuid": abcdef-12345,
    "username":"myUserName",
    "email":"name.surname@some-url.com",
    "private_email_flag": true
}
```

For an **unauthorized user**:

```
{
    "uuid": abcdef-12345,
    "username":"myUserName"
}
```

since the `email` field is private and options like `private_email_flag` should also be private.

What is the best practice to expose this data?

1. Have a single endpoint and return only public fields for unauthorized requests and all fields for authorized ones.
2. Use two different endpoints, e.g.:

   - `/users/abcdef-12345` - private - accessible only for authorized requests
   - `/user-profiles/abcdef-123465` - public - accessible by anybody
     Or, considering deeper resources, like user's articles:
   - `/users/abcdef-12345/articles/ghijk-67890` - private - accessible only for authorized requests
   - `/articles/ghijk-67890` - public - accessible to anybody

Or maybe (3.) something else.

Thank you!

Comment: I'm curious if you got any good advice on this? We're looking at this problem. Suggestions so far include (1) separate endpoints; (2) using a `media-type` header to distinguish "modes". Your method #1 was not recommended as it adds a lot of complexity when dealing with PUTs and other updates.

Comment: My final approach was to have a single endpoint and return different responses using this package: https://github.com/liip/sheriff trying to avoid the maintenance of too many endpoints (routes/handlers). But that was the balance I needed for my project, you should consider what's best for yours. Not sure I understand the complexity of updates, but it might be missing in my scenario as only the owner of an entity can update it and only GETs would need to differentiate responses.